# Finding $p(\tilde{y}|x)$ given measurement model and error distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, bivariate

Given two measurements of a variable $x$:

$\tilde{y_1}=x+e_1$

$\tilde{y_2}=x+e_2$

where $e_1,e_2$ are zero-mean random variables following a bivariate normal distribution, with a *known* joint probability density function $p(e_1,e_2)$. How can we find $p(\tilde{y}|x)$?

Comment: There is some issue with notation. $\tilde{y} = x + e_1$ and $\tilde{y} = x + e_2$ would imply $e_1 = e_2$.

Comment: Sorry, edited..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $x$, you know the joint density of $[e_1,e_2]$, which is also multivariate normal, with means $\mu_i+x$ for $i=1,2$ respectively. And that's about it, the density of $Y=[\tilde{y}_1,\tilde{y}_2]^T$ given $x$ will be the aforementioned Gaussian density: 
$$ f_{Y|x} = C\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(Y-\mu)^TM^{-1}(Y-\mu)\right),$$

where $\mu$ is the mean vector (given $x$), and $M$ is the covariance matrix, $cov(e_1,e_2)$, which is unchanged by different means.

Comment: What you have written imply that $f(\tilde{y}|x)=f(y_1,y_2)$. Why is this true?

Comment: It does not, since $\mu$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Each of $e_1,e_2$ have zero means. I don't see how $\mu$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Lets take a single variable, $y=x+e$, where $e$ is normal. The probability density of $y$ given $x$ is the same density of $e$, shifted by $x$. So, if $E[e]=0$, then $E[y|x]=E[x+e|x]=x+E[e]=x$.

Comment: Perfect, I see your point. So the conditional probability of $y$ given $x$ is the joint probability of the two measurements, $y_1, y_2$ both having a normal joint probability with the 'shifted' means. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: "Given", not "giving". Yes, if you, in general, have some random variable $Y=X+N$ and you seek the expectation of $Y$ given $X$, you will have $E[X|Y]=E[X|X]+E[N|X]=X+E[N]$, provided $X$ and $N$ are independent (or even just uncorrelated). And since a shifted Gaussian is still a Gaussian, you still have Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @ido did you mean $E[Y|X]=E[X|X]+E[N|X]=...$ in the comment above (rather than $E[X|Y]=...$)?